# How to use MUI theming in external CSS

Tags: material-ui

Currently, my application utilizes [in-file styling](https://bottom:%200%25;%20%20%20%20%20%20left:%2043%25;) (ie. `styled`) from MUI to customize components while incorporating MUI theming. However, I'd like to move my CSS customizations to an external CSS stylesheet and import that, rather having all HTML and CSS in one file. Is this possible? I haven't found any way to do this yet.

For example, a custom component could be:

```
const ProfileWrapper = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 3),
     boxShadow: theme.customShadows.z8,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
        padding: theme.spacing(0, 5)
    }
}));
```

However, I'm not sure how one would do `[theme.breakpoints.up('md')]` in a `.css` file and import it and use it as a class name for components.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as theme is a React element not css.

See here for all the ways you can organise styling in MUI https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/

I personally keep all my styled-components in a separate file.